# Magento product collection fetch based on special price end date in desc order of created date

Tags: product-collection, sorting, collection-filtering

I want to fetch product collection sorted in desc order of created date and filter it out if the special price end date is lower than current date.
I am able to sort it using this code.

```
if ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
    if(($this->getCurrentOrder())=='position'){
        $this->_collection->setOrder('entity_id','desc');
    } else {
       $this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(),$this->getCurrentDirection());
    }
}
```

But I cant filter this out further with special price end date < today's date.
Can anyone help? I will really appreciate it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$now = Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->gmtDate();
$this->_collection->addAttributeToFilter('special_to_date', array('or'=> array(
    0 => array('date' => true, 'from' => $now),
    1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
 ), 'left')
```

The code above should allow only products that don't have an end date for the special price or if the end date is in the future.

**[EDIT]**
To add a filter for `special_from_date` you can add this after the code above

```
$this->_collection->addAttributeToFilter('special_from_date', array('or'=> array(
    0 => array('date' => true, 'to' => $now),
    1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
), 'left')
```

Comment: Awesome. Works great. Thank you so much..

Comment: How can I filter if it should only show if today's date is between special price from date and special price to date? Kind of special price from date should be lower than today's date and special price to date should be higher than today's date.

special price from date < today's date & special price to date > today's date.

Thanks.

Comment: @hks. see my edit.

Comment: Thank you so much. That works great. Do you have any reference link where I can learn to make this kind of queries in Magento?

Comment: I took these and addapted them from the Catalog/Block/Product/New.php class.